# How does Qt's BorderLayout example work?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to modify the [borderlayout.cpp Example File](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layouts-borderlayout-borderlayout-cpp.html). In reading the code, however, I do not understand how the following lines work:

```
item->setGeometry(QRect(item->geometry().x(),
    item->geometry().y(), rect.width(),
    item->sizeHint().height());

southHeight += item->geometry().height() + spacing();

item->setGeometry(QRect(rect.x(),
     rect.y() + rect.height() - southHeight + spacing(),
     item->geometry().width(),
     item->geometry().height()));
```

Why is setGeometry called twice? Also, what/how is item->geometry() set to (I know that it is probably set by QLayout::setGeometry(rect), but looking at the source code for QLayout all that function does is assign rect to an internal pointer)?

The full function is:

```
void BorderLayout::setGeometry(const QRect &rect)
 {
     ItemWrapper *center = 0;
     int eastWidth = 0;
     int westWidth = 0;
     int northHeight = 0;
     int southHeight = 0;
     int centerHeight = 0;
     int i;

     QLayout::setGeometry(rect);

     for (i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
         ItemWrapper *wrapper = list.at(i);
         QLayoutItem *item = wrapper->item;
         Position position = wrapper->position;

         if (position == North) {
             item->setGeometry(QRect(rect.x(), northHeight, rect.width(),
                                     item->sizeHint().height()));

             northHeight += item->geometry().height() + spacing();
         } else if (position == South) {
             item->setGeometry(QRect(item->geometry().x(),
                                     item->geometry().y(), rect.width(),
                                     item->sizeHint().height()));

             southHeight += item->geometry().height() + spacing();

             item->setGeometry(QRect(rect.x(),
                               rect.y() + rect.height() - southHeight + spacing(),
                               item->geometry().width(),
                               item->geometry().height()));
         } else if (position == Center) {
             center = wrapper;
         }
     }

     centerHeight = rect.height() - northHeight - southHeight;

     for (i = 0; i item;
         Position position = wrapper->position;

         if (position == West) {
             item->setGeometry(QRect(rect.x() + westWidth, northHeight,
                                     item->sizeHint().width(), centerHeight));

             westWidth += item->geometry().width() + spacing();
         } else if (position == East) {
             item->setGeometry(QRect(item->geometry().x(), item->geometry().y(),
                                     item->sizeHint().width(), centerHeight));

             eastWidth += item->geometry().width() + spacing();

             item->setGeometry(QRect(
                               rect.x() + rect.width() - eastWidth + spacing(),
                               northHeight, item->geometry().width(),
                               item->geometry().height()));
         }
     }

     if (center)
         center->item->setGeometry(QRect(westWidth, northHeight,
                                         rect.width() - eastWidth - westWidth,
                                         centerHeight));
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to play with demo before. To answer your question, first setGeometry just to figure out the height of the item, then second setGeometry() place it in the bottom of the layout. 
When the item is placed south /bottom of the layout, you don't know how tall it is at first, right?

This is normal practice in GUI programming, for example, to place a string in label, you will try to place it anywhere, just to figure out height and length, after that you allocate the right rect, then place the string in the place you want.

Comment: If that were the case, why is it that thats not done for the North Position?

Comment: Because you know the location of north; while south is reverse calculated. To make it clear, you have a area say 100 by 100, when placing north, you place it at position (0,0), no problem. When placing south, you first figure out its height, say 25, then you place it at position (0, 100-25), right?